# xslt comma separate list of values

Tags: xslt

I am creating a summary view of Microsoft InfoPath form(s) using a custom XSLT Stylesheet.

I have a selection of the radio buttons on the form which are clicked "Yes", "No"

e.g.

```
 What is the primary construction of the building?

 Steel  Yes
        No

 Timber Yes
        NO

 etc....
```

In the stylesheet I have

```
          <tr>
            <td>
              The primary contruction of the building is
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/my:myFields/my:BrickPrimaryConstruction= 'true'">
                  Brick
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/my:myFields/my:TimberPrimaryConstruction  = 'true'">
                  Timber Framed
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/my:myFields/my:ConcretePrimaryConstruction  = 'true'">
                  Concrete Framed
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
              etc....
```

What I want to achieve in the final HTML output is something like:

```
The primary construction of the building is Brick, Concrete Framed, Prefabricated
```

I have not got much experience of XSLT, but what is the best way of achieving this?

Avoiding this:

```
, Concrete Framed, Prefabricated,
```

or

```
  Brick, , Prefabricated
```

Normally in C# I would assign to a string and check if it is empty before appending a comma and then trim commas on the ends however I know that I cannot assign variables in xslt.

**EDIT**

I also mentioned that I wanted to be able to reuse the function in other situations such as

```
              <xsl:value-of select="/my:myFields/my:Road"/>,
              <xsl:value-of select="/my:myFields/my:District"/>,
              <xsl:value-of select="/my:myFields/my:City"/>,
              <xsl:value-of select="/my:myFields/my:County"/>,
              <xsl:value-of select="/my:myFields/my:Postcode"/>
```

where these would be separated by comma or a new line character, but there is the possibility that the "District" for example might be blank resulting in "Road, , City" etc.

Comment: We can't guess what you want to display from a field. Also the XSLT processor can't. Please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        The primary contruction of the building is
        <xsl:for-each select="/my:myFields/my:*[ends-with(local-name(), 'PrimaryConstruction') and (.='true')]">
            <xsl:if test="position()!=1" xml:space="preserve">, </xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::my:BrickPrimaryConstruction">Brick</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="self::my:TimberPrimaryConstruction">Timber Framed</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="self::my:ConcretePrimaryConstruction">Concrete Framed</xsl:when>
                etc...
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Basically, the `for-each` loops over all the relevant fields, so that you can check their position and only emit the comma if you're not on the first item (XSLT has a 1-based index). Since the `for-each` already filters only the relevant entries, we then only have to check the type, not whether the value is `true` or not.

Note that you can extend the same principle to emit an "and" for the last item instead of a comma if you like to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I know that if I could use a loop this would be trivial, I would rather not use something that depended on the names of the fields if at all possible as I have a need to use the solution in many parts of the summary.

Comment: Instead of the part which checks the name you can of course also do this: `my:*[self::my:BrickPrimaryConstruction|self::my:TimberPrimaryConstruction|self::my:ConcretePrimaryConstruction]` - but since you need to know the first or the last item to correctly render the comma you're not going to come around some sort of "loop" or "list" with all matching items.

Comment: How can something so trivial be so awkward. Another thought that came to mind was using javascript code onload to tokenize and insert commas, but I would rather not.

Comment: I personally don't find it *that* awkward. I think that one of the difficulties with XSLT is getting used to the non-imperativeness, such as not being able to mutate variables and state. If you put that all in templates and then call `xsl:apply-templates select="."/>` instead of the `<xsl:choose>`, you can actually make it quite generic, so that you can re-use it for other fields as well.

Comment: Yes I agree, I am used to thinking in a more imperative manner and could definitely do with thinking in a more functional way however the reason why I do not want to depend on the naming convention is that I want to reuse the function elsewhere and it is a summary view where data is pulled from more than one (large) document - not all fields follow the same naming conventions.

Comment: I just picked up the naming convention because it *looked* as if this was fine, but of course, it it isn't, then by all means use the explicit XPath expression as shown.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I think I am looking at it the wrong way, but this solution works for me even if I have to copy it and amend it in places.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at [Implode](http://symphony-cms.com/download/xslt-utilities/view/22517/).

Then, you could do

```
<xsl:variable name="theItems">
    <xsl:if test="/my:myFields/my:BrickPrimaryConstruction= 'true'">
        <foo>Brick</foo>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:call-template name="implode">
    <xsl:with-param name="items" select="exsl:node-set($theItems)" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

You have to convert `$theItems`, which is a xml fragment, to a node-set. This can only be archived using non-standart methods. [XML.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html) shows some methods to archive it using various XML processors.

Comment: This looks promising, but it is saying that everything must be converted to a nodeset and then throws an exception.

Comment: It's not going to work, since the "items" param needs to hold a list of all items to start with, which is not achieved here.

Comment: @Lucero: Yes, I see. `$items` has to hold a node-set, but holds a xml fragment. It could be onverted, but only using non-standart methods.

Comment: @marc, that's right. With XSLT 2 however you could easily achieve what you need for your solution - but almost no product has XSLT 2 support (unfortunately)...

Comment: The edit has got the transform working, but it doesn't actually work all it does is put create a string like "BrickConcretePrefabricated" as a result